# File upload control in MVC - making it look for file in original location

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using a File Upload control in MVC project.

```
 <input type="file" name="file" id="Ids2" style="float:right"/>
```

I get the following error when I try to save the file (TestDocument.txt) in the database. Lets say I click on the upload button and then browser to location - "c:\TestDocument.txt" - and try to upload it, I get this error..

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\TestDocument.txt'.

Edit:(I am passing filename from the input type "file" value)

```
session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.PutAttachment(id,null, 
                    File.ReadAllBytes(@fileName), optionalMetaData);
```

Even though I select the text file from  C:\ location, it always look for the file in the above "C:\Program Files (x86)\Co....." location. How do I make it take the file from its original location. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show the form element (`@Html.BeginForm...` etc)?

Comment: It is just an MVC view (.ascx page) with bunch of divs and fieldsets with the usual <%@ Control Language="C#".....and <%@ import . ... > tags at the top of the page... there is no @Html.Beginform

Comment: If you want to post data or upload a file, you need a form element (unless you're using ajax). Can you also post the code where you try to save the file?

Comment: yes Im using ajax to pass the value to method in the controller. please see edited OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass the filename of the file to the server and expect to open the file using that filepath.  The path passed is on the clients local machine, but you are trying to open the file on the server.

You need a form element to post the actual file contents to the server.

Phil Haack has a good article with information on how to upload a file using MVC.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: Actually it is working and saving the attachment .. if I manually move the attachment to C:Program Files(x86)... folder and test.. so it is infact taking the file path and saving the document. My question is why its not picking up the document from the location I browsed to in the first place... why its looking in C:Priogram Files(x86) location..